# allocate matrix of struct

Tags: c, matrix, struct, typedef

i don't know what i'v been doing wrong. I am trying to create a matrix of struct that its elements are pointers to this struct:

```
typedef struct _Array
{
    short *arr;
    unsigned short size;
} Array;
```

I wrote a code that dynamically allocates the matrix but i'm getting an error because this line

```
mat[i][j]->arr = random_numbers(&mat[i][j]->size);
```

in the code below is wrong.

```
Array ***mat = (Array***)malloc(5 * sizeof(Array**));
for (short i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (short j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        *(mat + i) = (Array**)malloc(5 * sizeof(Array*));
        mat[i][j]->arr = random_numbers(&mat[i][j]->size);
    }
}
```

random_numbers is a function to return an array with random numbers and its size

```
short *random_numbers(unsigned short* pSize)
```

this is the error that i'm getting:
Exception thrown at 0x013F17F5 in app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.

Comment: Are you sure the triple pointer is necessary? If all you need is a 2D array, a double pointer should suffice.

Comment: How about giving us actual working code instead of making us guess what the other declarations and functions look like? I know you think you want to show only what's relevant, but if you knew what was relevant you wouldn't be asking us.

Comment: You are overwriting `*(mat + i)` on ever loop of `j`, you should put that line outside of the `for(short j = 0...)` loop

Comment: Notice that the name `_Array` is reserved for the implementation ([C11 §7.3.1 Reserved identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)).  Don't invent your own names that start with underscore and a capital letter or a second underscore.  Be cautious about all names starting with an underscore.

Comment: Tip: rather than use `5` and `5` in your demonstration code, use two different values, or better `ROWS` and `COLUMNS` to help distinguish their usage in allocation and `for()` iterations.  It adds clarity to your post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have allocated the space for the pointers, but did not for the structures. You derefence something which does not exists.

add:

```
    *(mat + i) = (Array**)malloc(5 * sizeof(Array*));
    mat[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(array));  //<<-allocate sace for the struct;
    mat[i][j]->arr = random_numbers(&mat[i ][j]->size);
```

Answer (score 0):

> To create a matrix of struct that its elements are pointers to this struct ...

Usually so many levels of indirection tend to be confusing and should be avoided.

Consider allocating to the size of of the `*pointer` rather than the `*pointer_type`.  It is easier to code correctly, review and maintain.

[@PeterJ_01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683453/2410359) rightly pointed out there is no allocation for `mat[][]`.  Also the allocation for `*(mat + i)` is in the wrong place.

```
typedef struct {
  short *arr;
  unsigned short size;
} Array;

short *random_numbers(unsigned short* pSize);

Array ***create_a_matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) {
  Array ***mat = malloc(sizeof *mat * rows);
  for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    mat[r] = malloc(sizeof *(mat[r]) * cols);
    for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      mat[r][c] = malloc(sizeof *(mat[r][c]));
      mat[r][c]->arr = random_numbers(&mat[r][c]->size);
    }
  }
  return mat;
}
```

Robust code would add error checking.  Example:

```
    mat[r] = malloc(sizeof *(mat[r]) * cols);
    // Added check and clean-up
    if (mat[r] == NULL && cols != 0) {
      while (r > 0) {
        free(mat[--r]);
      }
      free(mat);
      return NULL;
    }
```

I changed various variables names for clarity.